# Cannot return null for non-nullable field Mutation.createAds graphql error

Tags: node.js, graphql, prisma

I'm getting Cannot return null for non-nullable field Mutation.createAds. Error in altair graphql any help
I'm trying to upload multiples photos but I'm getting this error!
Hi, I'm getting Cannot return null for non-nullable field Mutation.createAds. Error in altair graphql any help
I'm trying to upload multiples photos but I'm getting this error

[image]

```
type ads {
    id:        String   
  user:        User
  titel:       String
  discription: String
  photo:       [photos]
  createdAt:   String
  updatedAt:   String
}
type photos{
  id:        String
  photo:     String
  Adses:     ads     
  createdAt: String
  updatedAt: String
}
   type Mutation{

createAds( titel:       String
                   discription: String
                   photo:       [Upload]):ads!
   }
}
```

Resolvers

```
createAds: async (_, {titel,
            discription,photo},{LogedInUser}) =>{
            userProtect(LogedInUser)

            
            const simo= await MultiplereadFiles(photo)
            console.log(simo)
            
            const create = Client.ads.create({data:{
  titel,
  discription,
  photos:simo,
  user:{
    connect:{
        id:LogedInUser.id
    }
  }

            }})
           
        
        },
```

Prisma schema

```
model ads {
  id          Int      @id
  user        User     @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  titel       String?
  discription String
  photo       photos[]
  files       String
  createdAt   DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt   DateTime @updatedAt
  userId      Int
}

model photos {
  id        Int      @id
  Adses     ads      @relation(fields: [adsId], references: [id])
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
  adsId     Int
}
```

Comment: after addin  return client.ads.create iget this message:

Answer (score 1):

The schema indicates a required response.
From the resolver snippet you shared, it seems there's no `return` to the function. Could it be the reason?
Either that, or there's something broken in your `Client.ads.create` logic